# Appcelerator and Urban Airship

Tags: appcelerator-mobile

I am trying out Urban Airship with Appcelerator but I am having problems with using it. 
This is my code in App.js:

Will it be "activated" when the user opens the app and then register automatically with Urban Airship?

```
UrbanAirship = require('ti.urbanAirship');

Ti.API.info("module is => "+UrbanAirship);

Ti.include('common/urbanairship.js');

UrbanAirship.key='XXX';
UrbanAirship.secret ='XXX';
UrbanAirship.master_secret='XXX';
UrbanAirship.baseurl = 'https://go.urbanairship.com';

Ti.Network.registerForPushNotifications({
  types: [
    Ti.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_BADGE,
    Ti.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_ALERT,
    Ti.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_SOUND
  ],
  success:function(e){
    var deviceToken = e.deviceToken;
    Ti.API.info('successfully registered for apple device token with '+e.deviceToken);
    var params = {
      tags: ['version'+Ti.App.getVersion()],
      alias: 'testing'
    };
    UrbanAirship.register(params, function(data) {
      Ti.API.debug("registerUrban success: " + JSON.stringify(data));
    }, function(errorregistration) {
      Ti.API.warn("Couldn't register for Urban Airship");
    });
  },
  error:function(e) {
    Ti.API.warn("push notifications disabled: "+e);
  },
  callback:function(e) {
    var a = Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
      title:'New Message',
      message:e.data.alert
    });
    a.show();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The modules are always hit or miss for me.

Very rarely have they worked without a lot of troubleshooting.

I've gone the old-school route and it has worked fine for me - although I did change `urbanairship.js` to add eventlisteners on windowfocus to the register/alias fields in the final app.

But for testing just leave as is. Hope this helps - http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Push+Notifications

Comment: Please include more than just a link to the answer, at least summarize what the key point is. This is so that if the link goes away, the future finder of this question can still have an answer to their question.